# React Native: How can you prevent the delaying of network requests when android app is in background?

Tags: android, background, react-native

When attempting to use fetch or websockets to send data when the app is in the background, react native is delaying the requests until the app comes back into the foreground.  Does anyone know of a way to send immediately?